# Laravel audio mime validator

Tags: validation, audio, mime-types, laravel-6

Hi there I have this validation:

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'podcast'  => 'requires|mimetypes:audio/mp3',
        ];
    }
```

And I upload an audio which is 1mb and its mp3 type, but it shows me the

```
The audio must be a file of type: audio/mp3 .
```

Instead of passing through the validation. I tried `'podcast'  => 'required|mimes:audio/mp3'`, also `'podcast'  => 'requires|mimes:mp3'`, But still nothing. Can someone help me what is it that I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

When I did this code the result is `bin` (note that I am posting an mp3 file):

```
dd($request->file('request_name')->guessExtension());
```

so instead of `requires|mimetypes:audio/mp3`, try to put `requires|mimetypes:bin`

Comment: if it's `bin` is becuase your `php.ini` is missconfigured regarding fields `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size`